# Reading in line by line in c?

Tags: c

I want to read in a text file that has this format:

```
3
COD
Halo
Madden
2
Tom Jones 1 3 2
Bill Ray 3 2 1
........
```

I want to figure out what the top video game choice between n number of people is by creating a voting system.
The first int is the number of games. Then there are 3 lines with video game names. Then there is an int representing the number of people, and then their names followed by their preference ranking of the games.

I need help getting start on this program.  Any advice?

Comment: Same author — this is arguably a superset of the other.  The other only asks about how to read the 'Tom Jones' lines; this asks a slightly more general question.

Answer (score 0):

See example below, it should get you started, it will read each line from the input file, and you can do whatever you need for each line:

```
#include <err.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    FILE *f;
    size_t len;
    char *line;

    f = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (line = fgetln(f, &len)) {
                /*DO whatever you need to do for each line here.*/
        fwrite(line, len, 1, stdout);
    }
    if (!feof(f))
        err(1, "fgetln");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the `<err.h>` header? It is not Standard C.  What is `fgetln()`?  It too is not Standard C?  It looks as though `fgetln()` returns a pointer — is that a new pointer for each line?  If so, you have a memory leak. If not, presumably you need to copy the line somewhere if you need to keep the value (contents of the line) across multiple calls (and you'd better not be using it in a threaded program, and the functions you call had better not use it, and ...).

Comment: fgetln() and err() are available in BSD systems, in mac as well

Comment: Hmmm...[`<err.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html) is a Linux manual page that notes the `err.h` is a non-standard BSD extension.  [`fgetln()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgetln&sektion=3) is a BSD function…as you noted…you need to be careful to identify non-standard functionality because it is depressingly probable that the OP is working on Windows, poor thing.

Answer (score 0):

sample like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct player {
    char *name;
    int  *rank;
} Player;

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    if(NULL==(fp=fopen("data.txt", "r"))){
        perror("file open");
        return -1;
    }
    //read name of game
    int numOfGame;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfGame);
    char gameName[numOfGame][64];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numOfGame;++i){
        fscanf(fp, "%63s", gameName[i]);
    }
    //read gamer 
    int numOfGamer;
    fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", &numOfGamer);
    Player players[numOfGamer];
    char line_buf[128];
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<numOfGamer;++i){
        fgets(line_buf, sizeof(line_buf), fp);
        char *p = strchr(line_buf, ' ');
        p = strchr(p+1, ' ');//second space
        *p = '\0';
        players[i].name = strdup(line_buf);
        players[i].rank = calloc(numOfGamer, sizeof(int));
        for(j = 0;j<numOfGame;++j){
            sscanf(++p, "%d", &players[i].rank[j]);
            p = strchr(p + 1, ' ');
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //test print
    printf("name\t\t");
    for(i=0;i<numOfGame;++i){
        printf("%s\t", gameName[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<numOfGamer;++i){
        printf("%s\t", players[i].name);
        for(j = 0;j<numOfGame;++j){
            printf("%d\t", players[i].rank[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //release
    for(i=0;i<numOfGamer;++i){
        free(players[i].name);
        free(players[i].rank);
    }
    return 0;
}
```